# Resize <Video> on Fallback to IE8 embedded in <Object>, Video gets Cropped

Tags: html, css, video, internet-explorer-8, html5-video

I have a video of Resolution **1166 X 720** in **mp4** Format.
The `<video>` tag works fine for IE9+,Chrome, Safari.
When I give `{width:90%}` to the video element ,It resizes properly to fit the screen size.

I am applying fallback to `<object>` by putting a Quick Time Player for IE8.
But now giving { width:90%;} to `<object>` doesn't resize the video instead **crops**
the video to adjust it's size.

I tried **VideoJS**, It's not rendering videos in IE8.
IE8 hates `<video>`, But I need to make it work.

Used **flowplayer** ,But the resizing problem keeps reoccuring.

What can be an feasible solution? Changing the resolution of the video 
or some CSS Hack for IE8 Fallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be worth trying an inline style, if you've not already ...

```
<object style="width:90%">
```

or wrap the video element in a div which you then size and make the video 100% width.